# Filter the type of file in AsyncFileUpload

Tags: asp.net, ajax

is there any way that I can filter the file that I will upload using AsyncFileUpload of ajax? 
This is the thing that I want to do, Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The AsyncFileUpload for web form do not have this option. Do you have to implement this validation.

Like this:

```
        switch (`"file.exe"`)
        {
            case "exe":
                OK = false;
                break;
            case "dll":
                OK = false;
                break;
        }
```

And when you upload the file, you have to call this method.

PS.: I'm sorry for my english, I'm brasilian and my english is very bad.

Answer (score 0):

Use below on code behind

```
 Protected Sub FileUploadComplete(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)



    Dim contentType As String = AsyncFileUploadProfileImage.ContentType

    If (contentType = "image/jpeg" Or contentType = "image/png") Then
        Dim filename As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(AsyncFileUploadProfileImage.FileName)
        AsyncFileUploadProfileImage.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("img_prof/") + filename)
    Else
        lblMesg.Text = "We support only images of type jpg and png"
    End If

End Sub
```